# "Rechtsprechung" vs "Rechtssprechung"

Tags: meaning, compound, legal-terminology

Besteht ein Unterschied zwischen 'Rechtsprechung' und 'Rechtssprechung' in der deutschen Sprache und, spezieller, in der juristischen Fachsprache?

'Rechtsprechung' taucht auf im Grundgesetz der BRD, Art. 20(3):

> Die Gesetzgebung ist an die verfassungsmäßige Ordnung, die vollziehende Gewalt und die Rechtsprechung sind an Gesetz und Recht gebunden.

'Rechtssprechung' ist was ich als juristischer Laie im Alltag von mir geben würde. Besteht da ein Unterschied in der Bedeutung, ist es lediglich ein häufiger Fehler, oder wurde gar die Orthografie geändert?

Answer (score 4):

Beide Formen sind gültig, [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Rechtsprechung) nennt *Rechtssprechung* als **Nebenform**; ich vermute, dass das Fugen-*s* sich wegen aufwändiger separater Aussprache nicht so aufdrängt. [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut) gibt bei zusammengesetzten Substantiven eine Quote von 72,8% für *keinen Fugenlaut* an.

Answer (score 2):

Es ist eine traditionelle Eigenschaft des Amtsdeutschen - anscheinend vor allem in Deutschland - (z. B. in Gesetzen und Verordnungen), dass dort i. A. auf das Fugen-s verzichtet wird. Warum? Keine Ahnung.

In der Präambel zum Grundgesetz der Bundesrepublik Deutschland kommt auf jeden Fall *verfassung**s**gebend* vor, was den Petitionsausschuß einige Jahre lang beschäftigt hat und fast zu einer Verfassungsänderung (zur Tilgung dieses "s") geführt hätte. Inzwischen hat man sich anscheinend auf "kann man so lassen" geeinigt.

Zu deiner speziellen Frage: Nein, in diesem speziellen Fall (und in den meisten anderen Fällen, wo ein Fugen-s im Amts- und Behördendeutsch weggelassen wird), besteht keinerlei Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen den beiden Versionen. *Rechts**s**prechung* und *Rechtsprechung* meint dasselbe.

Es gibt allerdings eine geringe Anzahl von eher nationalen Unterschieden im Deutschen, wo tatsächlich ein Fugen-s einen Bedeutungsunterschied herstellen kann - das hat allerdings mehr Ursache in der traditionellen nationalen Begriffsdefinition als in der Sprache selbst:

Der *Zugführer* bei der Eisenbahn ist sowohl im "deutschen" Deutsch als auch in Österreich die Person, die an Bord die Verantwortung für einen Eisenbahnzug von A nach B trägt. In Deutschland kann ein *Zugführer* auch einen Zug (eine Einheit) von Soldaten bei der Bundeswehr führen - Im österreichischen Bundesheer is das ein *Zug**s**führer* - da ist das tatsächlich ein Dienstgrad (und er darf verwirrenderweise tatsächlich keinen *Zug*, sondern höchstens eine *Gruppe* führen...).

Andrerseits ist - um beim Zug zu bleiben - ein deutscher *Schnellzugwagen* genau dasselbe wie ein schweizer *Schnellzug**s**wagen*.

Comment: Weitere Informationen zB hier: https://bastiansick.de/kolumnen/zwiebelfisch/bratskartoffeln-und-spiegelsei/

Answer (score -4):

Moin,

es gibt ihn wirklich, den vermeintlichen Unterschied:

1.)
Rechtssprechung ist Begriffsbildung aus dem Rechtswesen. Die Bedeutung ist (formal-)rechtlicher Art. Ein Plural ist Rechtssprechungen.

2.)
Rechtsprechung ist gutdeutsches Synonym für Orthoepie. Es geht darin um sprachgemäße Aussprache, allgemeiner Geräuschumsetzung, sehsprachlicher Elemente, z.B. sehsprachliches Wort.
Die Synonymie zwischen Rechtsprechung (Rechtlautung) und Orthoepie entspricht der Synonymie zwischen Rechtschreibung und Orthographie.

Comment: Gibt es dafür Belege?

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthoepie

Comment: Der verlinkte Artikel belegt ja gerade, das "Rechtsprechung" _nicht_ Orthoepie bedeutet, sondern "Rechtlautung" verwendet wird.

Comment: Wir sollten eine "wrong answers only"-Version dieses SE anlegen lassen, for the lulz.